# Variable "is not blueprint visible" in function library

Tags: unreal, blueprints, unreal-5

I am trying to create a function that simply returns some hardcoded values so that I can use them in other functions within the function library. However, I'm getting the error:

```
GetGridMeasurements.HexHeight is not blueprint visible (BlueprintReadOnly or BlueprintReadWrite). Please fix mark up or cease accessing as this will be made an error in a future release.
```

[image]

I'm pretty new to Unreal (currently using 5.1) and don't really understand what this means. I created everything through the UI and haven't touched any C++. I realize I could just return the values without making variables but I am still wondering why this specifically doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue ended up being caused by having a local variable wired to an output parameter of the same name. Changing the output parameter name resolved the issue.

Comment: As an aside, I've found that it's probably better to use a struct for these values anyway but this was my initial idea for dealing with a lack of static class variables in Unreal.